# How can I use the reduce() function in python to search a list?

Tags: python, reduce

How can I use the reduce() function in python to search a list for a key? From what I've seen it is only useful for getting sums.

Comment: If you saw it's "only useful for getting sums", then why ask how to use it for searching? Why do you want to use `reduce` when clearly there are better options?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `reduce` for this. Just use:

```py
key in my_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to optionally append to a result list with the elements that meet your search criteria:

```
from functools import reduce

L = ['Apple','Banana','Orange','Grape']

sr = reduce(lambda a,s: a+[s]*('n' in s),L,[]) # items containing 'n'

print(sr)

['Banana', 'Orange']
```

The initial value is an empty list (the `a` parameter of the lambda). Each element of L (`s` parameter) is added to the resulting list if it contains 'n'.  `[s]*('n' in s)` Multiplies a one item list containing `s` by the result of the criteria check ('n' in s) resulting in either an empty list (when criteria is not met) or a list containing `s`which is then concatenated with the cumulative result (`a`)

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x if x == 7 else y, some_list, None)
```

This will return `7` if `some_list` contains `7`. The logic here is basically you use the accumulator as just a holder of the result. If you found whatever you're looking for you pass it on, otherwise you pass the "accumulator" knowing it either already contains the found value or whatever it started with.

Note: we're not here to do your coursework. Show what approaches you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools 
lis = [ 1 , 3, 5, 6, 2, ] 
  
print ("The sum of the list elements is : ",end="") 
print (functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a+b,lis)) 

print ("The maximum element of the list is : ",end="") 
print (functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a if a > b else b,lis))
```

Comment: This answers the question how?